# File not found in /data/media/0, but found in /storage/emulated/0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I use the smartphone emulator in Android Studio for a Nexus 4, API 23.

I took a picture through its camera, and I can check that the file is present at this different paths through the Android Device Monitor:

```
/data/media/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160408_143726.jpg (rw-rw-r)
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160408_143726.jpg (rw-rw)
```

[image: Android Device Monitor]

Nevertheless, in my `Activity` I got different behaviors when I try to read the file:

```
new File("/data/media/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160408_143726.jpg");
// isFile at false, canRead at false, length at 0

new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160408_143726.jpg");
// isFile at true, canRead at true, length with a real value
```

Why is it so?

Comment: `and I can check that the file is present `. You forgot to tell how you checked that.

Comment: You're right. I edited the question to explain that it's trough the Android Device Monitor.

Comment: Under wich catedory are those paths? The same?

Comment: I'm not sure what to answer as I don't know what you're calling a category :/

Comment: And i dont know whete you could see them. Are they displayed in the same block in successive lines? In the same view?

Comment: They are not displayed in views: I checked these paths with the Android Device Monitor.

Comment: What ever that is, you could better tell how you see them. Or post a screendump. Any commands used? I try to help you and you give null,null info.

Comment: I'm new to Android Studio, I thought Android Device Monitor was a known tool, as it's packaged with Android Studio. Here, I edited the question with a screenshot of what the tool gives me.

Comment: Thanks. So in the File Explorer. In a tree view. Mmmm. Strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it depends on contructor, use this method to get the sdcard path instead, that will find the correct path for all devices

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160408_143726.jpg")
```

Comment: How in the world can this explain those two paths? It has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: It doesn't explain the two paths difference but seems to resolve my problem, providing me the right path to use. Still, I wonder why one path works only.

Comment: As it is no answer to your question its wrong to check it as correct.

Comment: For the DCIM directory there is a separate system call which you better could use. But you never asked for such help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would like to grant your app root permission so as to let it work properly. Take a look at this example:

```
u0_a1@android:/ $ toolbox ls -l /storage/emulated/0/UPDATE*
-rw-rw---- root    sdcard_r  4997896 2016-09-08 20:08 UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.78.zip
u0_a1@android:/ $ toolbox ls -l /data/media/0/UPDATE*
/data/media/0/*: Permission denied
1|u0_a1@android:/ $ su
root@android:/ # toolbox ls -l /data/media/0/UPDATE*
-rw-rw-r-- media_rw media_rw  4997896 2016-09-08 20:08 UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.78.zip
```